# Questions about OAuth screening when using Google Fit with Android apps

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm developing an Android app that uses Google Fit. When preparing to publish the application, there are the following unclear points regarding OAuth examination.
please help me.

- Do android apps that use the Fitness API require Google's OAuth review?
- I need to set a sensitive scopes when using the Fitness API in an Android app?
- What is the work and information required for Google's OAuth review?　Is there a reference site?
- Regarding the homepage URL required for Google's OAuth review,Ssnce the Android app　homepage will be published just before the Android app is published on the Play Store, it cannot be prepared at the pre-screening stage.
  If you have such a situation, please tell us the best response. Is the homepage URL essential information for the examination?

Answer (score 0):

Google Fit scopes are considered sensitive, therefore you'll need to submit verification once you publish your app to production.

I'd recommend this post from Google for what you need to prepare for the verification process.

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en